# "Then $Ax=b$ implies $cx=\delta$, if and only if there is a row vector $y$ such that $yA=c$ and $yb=\delta$."

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> **Corollary 3.1b**
>
> The system $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $yb=0$ for each vector $y$ with $yA=0$.
>
> **Corollary 3.1d**
>
> Let $A$ be a matrix, $b$ be a column vector, $c$ be a row vector and $\delta$ be a number. Assume that $Ax=b$ has a solution. **Then $Ax=b$ implies $cx=\delta$, if and only if there is a row vector $y$ such that $yA=c$ and $yb=\delta.$**
>
> **Proof:**
>
> The sufficiency of the condition is trivial. To see necessity, let $x_0$ be a solution of $Ax=b$, and suppose that $Ax=b$ implies $cx=\delta$. Then in particular $cx_0=\delta$. Then: $Ax=0$ gives $A(x+x_0)=b$ gives $c(x+x_0) = \delta$ gives $cx=0$. Therefore by **Corollary 3.1b**, $yA=c$ for some row vector $y$. This vector also satisfies $yb=\delta.$

This is from Alexander Schrijver's *Theory of Linear and Integer Programming*. I'm confused about the boldfaced part and how **Corollary 3.1b** is being applied.

Another confusion is how to interpret the word 'implies': should I consider $Ax=b$ and $cx=\delta$ as two given conditions or does the connection of these two conditions also have meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rewrite $yA = c$ as $A^T y^T = c^T$. We are interested in a solution for this system of linear equations. The existence of a solution shows that we must have $yA = c$ for some $y$. By corollary 3.1b we need to prove that $zc^T = 0$ for each row vector $z$ so that $zA^T = 0$. Hence, let $z$ be a row vector so that $zA^T = 0$. Then, we have $A z^T = 0$. Hence, $cz^T = 0$ (this is shown, in the proof you gave, before corollary 3.1b is mentioned). This implies that $zc^T = 0$. Hence, by corollary 3.1b we must have that $A^T y^T = c^T$ has a solution. Which means that there exists a (column) vector $y^T_*$ so that $A^T y^T_* = c^T$. Hence, there exists a row vector $y_*$ such that $y_* A = c$.

The second part follows from the existence of such solution and the assumption that $Ax = b$. Let $y$ be a row vector so that $yA = c$, then
$$
cx = \delta \implies (yA)x =\delta \implies y(Ax) =\delta \implies yb =\delta
$$

Your last question is answered by the other user.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an intuition about your last question, the statement is of the form
$$(a \implies b) \iff c.$$
So to prove it, you should prove both directions $[\implies]$ and $[\impliedby]$.

To prove $[\implies]$ you should start from your theorem assumptions, reach $a$ which gives you (without proving it) $b$, and from there you conclude $c$.

To prove $[\impliedby]$, assume that $c$ is true, start from $a$, use your theorem assumptions and $c$ to find $b$.